# Find value of optgroup in DDL

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a dropdownlist that is created by this:

**C#:**

---

```
public static List<SelectListItem> lstDailySumAssignments()
{
    List<SelectListItem> lstAssignments = new List<SelectListItem>();

    using(var context = new AviationLogsEntities())
    {
        List<codeAC> lstActivity = context.codeAC.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

        List<string> lstCategories = new List<string>() { "STH", "NT", "STHLVGMA", "CS",
                                                              "S&R", "R", "S", "P", "D", "T", "P", "REFUSAL", "SERVICE & TESTING", "SE", "E",
                                                              "AG", "P", "P", "DA", "HTH",
                                                              };

        List<string> lstTraining = new List<string>() { "SEH", "MEH", "SEA", "IT", "HT", "ELT",
                                                            "TO", "CSEH", "CMEH", "CSEA" };

        var groups = lstActivity.OrderBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).ThenBy(x => lstTraining.IndexOf(x.text)).ThenBy(x => x.text).GroupBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).OrderBy(g => lstCategories.IndexOf(g.Key));
        foreach(var group in groups)
        {
            var slg = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key };

            foreach(codeAC activity in group)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = slg };
                lstAssignments.Add(item);
            }
        }

    }

    return lstAssignments;
}
```

---

Now my **JavaScipt:**

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#activityID').change(function () {
        var selectedActivity = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
        if (selectedActivity === "STH") {
            $('#EnsureTransport').show();
        }
        else if (selectedActivity !== "STH") {
            $('#EnsureTransport').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

---

Now this works perfectly, but it is rather static and not dynamic to user changes.  So instead of comparing against the literal string.. is there a way to compare against the order of the groups? So since `STH` is the first group, or `<optgroup>` as its rendered in HTML, can I compare against that?

As an example of what I am trying to explain I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#activityID').change(function () {
        var selectedActivity = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.value;
        if (selectedActivity === 1) {
            $('#EnsureTransport').show();
        }
        else if (selectedActivity !== 1) {
            $('#EnsureTransport').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

but this does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm correct, you want to get the index (order) of the `<optgroup>` in your `<select>` for the selected `<option>`.

Given a basic HTML example like:

```
<select id="activityID">
  <optgroup label="STH">
    <option value="1">Activity 1</option>
    <option value="2">Activity 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="OTHER">
    <option value="3">Activity 3</option>
    <option value="4">Activity 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ANOTHER">
    <option value="5">Activity 5</option>
    <option value="6">Activity 6</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#activityID').change(function () {
    var selected = $("option:selected", this);
    var groupIndex = selected.parent().index();

    console.log(groupIndex);
  });
});
```

The output would be:

> Activity 1 -> 0
>
> Activity 2 -> 0
>
> Activity 3 -> 1
>
> Activity 4 -> 1
>
> Activity 5 -> 2
>
> Activity 6 -> 2

So in your example, one could use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#activityID').change(function () {
    var selected = $("option:selected", this);
    var selectedActivity = selected.parent().index();

    if (selectedActivity === 0) {
      $('#EnsureTransport').show();
    }
    else if (selectedActivity !== 0) {
      $('#EnsureTransport').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

*Note that indexes start from 0 and not 1.*

Comment: any documentation on this? I am reviewing [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) but can't find `.index()` or `.parent()`

Comment: Sure, since your example showed that you're using jQuery, I decided to use their helper functions to get a cleaner syntax since it's there. You can find the documentation here: [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) & [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: Thank you. Also, where/how did you know to put `this` after `"option:selected"`? I mean I know what that does, but I can't seem to find that either.